# PHP not getting JSON values sent from retrofit

Tags: php, json, kotlin

I'm sending values `user` and `id` as JSON values to server using POST request.

On server I'm getting values using:

```
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$json = json_decode($data, true);

if (array_key_exists('user', $json) && array_key_exists('id', $json)) {
 ...
 echo "received";
}
else {
 ...
 echo "not received";
}
```

But it always ends in `"not received"`.

I tried to throw new Exception to see values for `$data` and for `$json`, and here is what I got:

```
Uncaught Exception: $data:"{\"user\":\"usr\",\"id\":\"0\"}"
Uncaught Exception: $json:{"user":"usr","id":"0"}
```

It should work, but it's not working for some strange reason.

If I replace `$data = file_get_contents('php://input');` with `$data = "{\"user\":\"usr\",\"id\":\"0\"}";`, then it works.

But if I replace `$json = json_decode($data, true);` with `$json = "{'user':'usr','id':'0'}";`, then it's not working.

I also tried to run this code in PhpStorm and it works normally. I tried replacing both `$data` and `$json` with their actual values and it works all the time, like it should work.

Does anyone have any idea why it doesn't work on the server?

EDIT:

Kotlin part:

```
@Headers("Content-type:application/json")
@POST("user.php")
suspend fun getUsers(@Body body: String): List<User>
```

---

```
val jsonObject = JSONObject()
jsonObject.put("user", user)
jsonObject.put("id", "" + id)

val users = network.getUsers(jsonObject.toString())
```

Comment: It looks like you get sent a JSON-encoded JSON-string?! I.e, `json_decode(json_decode($data), true)` might work?

Comment: Please link the retrofit documentation. It seems there is some double encoding going on as `$data` should not contain `{\"`.

Comment: Also for your testing a JSON String can only have DoubleQuotes, single quotes are not legal JSON so that's why `"{'user_id':'testuid','page_number':'0'}"` wont work

Comment: Might be useful to see how you SEND (Build) The JSON in the AJAX Call

Comment: Or a simple `$data = file_get_contents('php://input'); echo $data;`

Comment: what does json_last_error() return?

Comment: FWIW, your variables are named backwards. What you get from `php://input` is a *JSON string*. What you have when you decode it is *data*…

Comment: @deceze yes, you are right, variables are named backwards. Also your solution with `json_decode(json_decode($data), true), true)` works! You can post it as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @deceze only I'm not sure why JSON is formatted like that, so that I have to use twice `json_decode`? I added my Kotlin code if it helps.

Comment: @deceze its a matter of taste. He/she is getting "request data" from php://input into `$data` and has a decoded "json" object in `$json`. I like that more than yours.

Comment: @Daniel Sure, in the end variable naming is all arbitrary and subjective, but what you get back from `json_decode` *is objectively not JSON*…

Comment: @deceze I don't agree with you. I like a more semantic approach. What you get back from json_decode is the PHP representation of a JSON object, naming the variable `$json` is accurate. A variable named `$data`... ok.... every variable contains "data", so it's not wrong but not accurate.

Comment: @Daniel JSON is only the *transport encoding*. You could substitute it with YAML or XML or a lot of other such encodings. How much sense does it make to name data after its origin? If you pass the decoded data around to other parts of your app, will you keep it named after the format from which it originated? At some point you should start calling it something useful, like "`customers`", or "`cars`", or whatever it is that it actually contains.

Comment: @deceze If I pass the data arround to other objects they get the name of what they are just like with `$json`: `$json = json_decode($requestData); $customer = $this->hydrator->hydrate($json, Customer::class);` Your approach is very syntactical, sticking to what the syntax returns, mine is semantic, containing the meaning of the thing.

Comment: The problem is sending - the first test is proof, the second one can't work because you can't put json as associative array in php.
POST - the output is garbled or empty - check it in php - at the beginning of the file `var_dump ($ _ POST);` if nothing was sent, you will get `array (0) {}`